# Renaming JSON fields after the JSON is parsed, but before it's returned as a response

Tags: java, json, jackson

Incoming JSON:

```
{
"start_date": 12345
},
{
"start_date": 12345
},
```

ItemDTO:

```
public class ItemDto {
  Long start_date;
}
```

[TODO] Transform the `start_date` field to `date`

Outgoing JSON:

```
{
"date": 12345
},
{
"date": 12345
},
```

How would I go about accomplishing the `TODO` part of this process? I've tried using `@JsonProperty` on the variable and on the getters and setters.

Comment: Your approach using the ```@JsonProperty``` on getters and setters is correct, what did you get?

Comment: It didn't properly set the value. I'll try again.

Comment: I believe I was using the same method name and the duplicate answer seems to indicate that you need to name them different so Jackson parses them separately.